# "Maximize" pygame window

Tags: python, windows, pygame, python-3.10

How do I "maximize" a window in pygame, with "maximize" I mean this:

[image: an almost maximized window]

Not this:

[image]

Do you have any idea of how can this be done?

Comment: These images in the question do not show a [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) window. These images show the console window.

Answer (score 1):

You can maximize the Pygame window using the set_mode() method and passing the pygame.FULLSCREEN argument:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

# your code here

pygame.quit()
```

This will make the window display in full screen. If you want to exit full screen mode, just press the "Esc" key or call the set_mode() method again, this time without the pygame.FULLSCREEN argument.

Comment: And what if I already have an ".RESIZABLE" in the place, will it work?